# Oracle to_date function. Mask needed

Tags: oracle, format, mask, to-date

I have string of date from xml file of such kind: '2010-09-09T22:33:44.OZ'

I need to extract only date and time. I want to ignore symbol T and .OZ (time zone). Which mask I should use? Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a XSD date xs:dateTime to an Oracle Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549068/converting-a-xsd-date-xsdatetime-to-an-oracle-date)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
select TO_DATE('2010-09-09T22:33:44.OZ'
              ,'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS".OZ"')
from dual;

9/09/2010 10:33:44 PM
```

Answer (score 6):

If the timezone information is needed:

```
select to_timestamp_tz('2010-09-09T22:33:44.GMT','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.TZR')
from dual;

09-SEP-10 22.33.44.000000000 GMT
```

But `OZ` isn't a recognised timezone abbreviation, so you'd need to do some pre-conversion of that to something that is.

If you want to just ignore that part, and it's fixed, you can do what @Jeffrey Kemp said:

```
select to_date('2010-09-09T22:33:44.OZ','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS."OZ"')
from dual;

09/09/2010 22:33:44 -- assuming your NLS_DATE_FORMAT is DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS
```

If you want to ignore it but it isn't fixed then you'll need to trim it off first, something like (using a bind variable here for brevity):

```
var input varchar2(32);
exec :input := '2010-09-09T22:33:44.OZ';
select to_date(substr(:input,1,instr(:input,'.') - 1),'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS')
from dual;

09/09/2010 22:33:44
```

Comment: Oh, OK, so I guess that means the timezone part can be ignored. In which case @Jeffrey's answer is rather more succinct.

Comment: Thanks APC, I initially thought OZ was some kind of unofficial Australian timezone :)