# How can I insert Date Time with WSO2 Data Service in Oracle

Tags: oracle, date, xsd, wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I need to insert datetime information with WSO2 Data Service in Oracle date field. I created an Oracle procedure to insert a record.

The WSO2 map considers:

```
< param name="execution" sqlType="DATE" ordinal="17" />
```

And for execute the DS, I used:

```
< xs:execution xmlns:xs="ds.exec.com.br">2011-04-01T08:10:00</xs:execution>
```

I tried use the query like this:

```
INSERT INTO xxxx (execution) 
     VALUES (to_date(p_execution,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'));
```

Someone can help-me please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a XSD date xs:dateTime to an Oracle Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549068/converting-a-xsd-date-xsdatetime-to-an-oracle-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use "TIMESTAMP" as the "sqlType" of your input mapping as shown below.

```
<param name="execution" sqlType="TIMESTAMP" ordinal="17"/>
```